# API Gateway randomly switching responses from 403 to 404

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have API Gateway set up to serve some files from S3 bucket with Lambda. When I try to request non-existing files, API Gateway sometimes responds with `403 Forbidden` (most of the times and doesn't even trigger Lambda function) and sometimes with `404 Not Found` error (I'd like to trigger 404 in such cases).

My Lambda function is very simple:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    const Bucket = 'testing-bucket';
    const Key = `${event.documentType}/${event.requestParams.document}`;
    const file = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();

    return {
      body: file.Body.toString('base64'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=test.jpg`,
        'Content-Length': file.ContentLength,
        'Content-Type': file.ContentType,
      },
      statusCode: 200,
      isBase64Encoded: true,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: `[${e.code}] ${e.message}` }),
      statusCode: e.statusCode,
    };
  }
};
```

IAM Role attached to Lambda function is configured in this way:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testing-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testing-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Caching is completely disabled in API Gateway and the command I've been trying to test this out is:

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: 123xyz' -H 'Accept: image/jpeg' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -I https://test.com/existing_folder/non-existing-file.xxx
```

Responses are:

```
HTTP/2 403
content-type: application/json
content-length: 60
date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 10:32:30 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: ae870104-9045-4c23-9794-226992bad591
x-amzn-errortype: AccessDeniedException
x-amz-apigw-id: BMAZwGSyoAMFftw=
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 ccf34ecc11e5579d8083b17d9d39a622.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: LHR62-C2
x-amz-cf-id: zgtgfJX9TQLcI8F2RLWdgTz-RN_1j7MXblQ1498ucoeFY3dhjitOdg==
```

and

```
HTTP/2 404
content-type: application/json
content-length: 59
date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 10:32:31 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: 2de49681-4f21-4cd1-989c-9b36327badb1
x-amz-apigw-id: BMAZ5E52IAMFwEg=
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-5d9b143f-aadf0a24a5f60f4c939b77c0;Sampled=0
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 be00537a2361673ea48963d6e04d04a1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: LHR62-C2
x-amz-cf-id: 9VI26GH3-ZuJSQrEt5Fc7EjuMt8IV0TPzPwna8dvvr6UtsgiqwwIkw==
```

How to make API Gateway respond in consistent way?

---

#### UPDATE:

After observing API Gateway logs and trying to spam the same `curl` command for existing and non-existing files couple of times in a row, this was the output for non-existing file (timestamps are intact):

```
# curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: 123xyz' -H 'Accept: image/jpeg' -H 'cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=1, s-maxage=1'  https://my.url/foo/nobar

{
    "requestId": "d19602e8-3a32-4445-b9e6-99f05a59fac4",
    "ip": "redacted",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "08/Oct/2019:00:05:03 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/foo/{bar}",
    "status": "404",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "59"
}

# and

{
    "requestId": "b33bf6c7-55db-4e1f-b4e4-b1e826139556",
    "ip": "redacted",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "08/Oct/2019:00:05:05 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/foo/{bar}",
    "status": "403",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "60"
}
```

and for existing file:

```
# curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: 123xyz' -H 'Accept: image/jpeg' -H 'cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=1, s-maxage=1'  https://my.url/foo/bar

{
    "requestId": "122ef31e-c587-470c-a0b5-51c6d9838fe4",
    "ip": "redacted",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "07/Oct/2019:23:58:35 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/foo/{bar}",
    "status": "403",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "60"
}

# and then later

{
    "requestId": "c8ad1b40-006f-4d03-9d10-c6d91e366380",
    "ip": "redacted",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "07/Oct/2019:23:59:58 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/foo/{bar}",
    "status": "200",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "80280"
}
```

Comment: You are asking about how to make API Gateway respond a certain way, but it appears to be *your Lambda function* that is generating the response... so, how is your Lambda function actually responding?  What's in the response body you receive from the curl commands?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot My question is about "API Gateway" because it is ultimately responsible for all the responses, whether they are 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx. My Lambda is generating response in exact way I shared in my question, and final response body is simple JSON, depending on the error: `{"message":"[NoSuchKey] The specified key does not exist."}` for 404 errors (the ones I'm able to catch in my `try/catch` block) and `{"Message":"User is not authorized to access this resource"}` for 403 errors which are generic AWS errors because in those cases my Lambda function is not triggered at all.

Comment: You didn't mention that the Lambda function wasn't being triggered, so the fact that the object doesn't exist wouldn't be part of the issue.  What does API Gateway itself write to the logs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot True, I didn't mention that part, I did mention it later in comments of current proposed answer, I will update my question to make that clear. I didn't check out API Gateway logs since I got only Lambda CloudWatch logs access, I'll try to check it out when I get back to computer, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot updated my question with more details. Not sure how useful tho, all this makes no sense to me at this point at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got some time to get back to this issue and it looks like the problem was all along in "authorizer" function which had caching enabled, once disabled, my responses started to respond in a consistent way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the response yourself. You can check if the file doesn't exist after your await and respond a 404. Something like this: (Code not tested)

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    const Bucket = 'testing-bucket';
    const Key = `${event.documentType}/${event.requestParams.document}`;
    const file = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();

    if (!file) {
      return {
        body: {error: 'File not found'},
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        statusCode: 400,      
      };
    }

    return {
      body: file.Body.toString('base64'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=test.jpg`,
        'Content-Length': file.ContentLength,
        'Content-Type': file.ContentType,
      },
      statusCode: 200,
      isBase64Encoded: true,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: `[${e.code}] ${e.message}` }),
      statusCode: e.statusCode,
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I can easily catch 404 errors in my `catch` block and respond in any way I need, however, in case of 403 (when requesting exactly the same non-existing file), my Lambda function is not triggered at all, so I cannot handle that case myself.

Comment: According to the documentation: If a user doesn’t have s3:ListBucket permissions, then the user gets Access Denied errors for missing objects instead of 404 Not Found errors. Run the head-object AWS CLI command to check if an object exists in the bucket. So you have to check your permissions https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/

Comment: But I did set `Allow` to `s3:ListBucket` in my policy. After reading some other related issues here on SO, I even expanded my `Resource` part to include bucket name with and without wildcard. I wasn't aware of head-object, but I'm not sure if that method would help me in my use case at all (again, since 403 doesn't even trigger the Lambda function).

Comment: Do you have any load balancing setup?  This seems like a problem I had a few years back...where one request would work, and then another would fail, and we couldn't figure out why...until we looked at our load balancing and one of the balancers had access and the other did not...which would alternate the response messages...if you have load balancing enabled, you might want to check out the permissions there...

Comment: @KevinMansel I had similar experience with ELB and EBS, but for this purpose I didn't configure any load balancer, and if it is of any relevance, my API's "Endpoint Type" is set to "Regional". The whole configuration should be really simple, I didn't use almost any custom configuration in my API...

Answer (score 0):

So when I wrote my lambda to process s3 downloads, I did stick with promise chaining so that I could debug easier...have you tried the other method?

```
return s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise().then((s3Response) => {
    console.log(s3Response.Body.toString());
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I have a feeling there is something happening in your promise that's causing it to come back to quick and it's failing or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't occur to me to try out different JS methods of accessing the file, but unfortunately after trying your suggestion along with the same method from official docs (regular JS callbacks), the behaviour is more or less the same :/

Comment: dang...wish I could help ya here.  hopefully you figure out the bug.  